# How to dynamically add elements to an SVG image with jquery?

Tags: jquery, svg

If I dynamically load some svg data inside an svg image, I can see it when inspecting the DOM, but it doesn't actually appear in the browser. Below is a simple example, where I try to put a small rectangle inside a bigger rectangle. The pre-combined SVG image, with the exact same contents, works, but when I try to combine them on the fly with jquery, the inner rectangle never shows up. What am I misunderstanding?

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SVG test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#already-combined").load("test_combined.svg svg"); //works
    $("#combine").load("test_outer.svg svg", function() {
        $(this).find("svg").append("<g id=\"appended\"></g>");
        // present when inspecting DOM, but is never visible...
        $("#appended").load("test_inner.svg svg > *");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Already combined...</h3>
<div id="already-combined"></div>
<h3>Combine in javascript...</h3>
<div id="combine"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

test_combined.svg:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect x="1" y="1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" width="75" height="75"/>
  <g>
    <rect x="25" y="25" fill="none" stroke="#000000" width="25" height="25"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

test_outer.svg:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect id="outer" x="1" y="1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" width="75" height="75"/>
</svg>
```

test_inner.svg:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect id="inner" x="25" y="25" fill="none" stroke="#000000" width="25" height="25"/>
</svg>
```

Here is the DOM as seen by inspecting in firefox:

```
<html><head>
<title>SVG test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#already-combined").load("test_combined.svg svg");
    $("#combine").load("test_outer.svg svg", function() {
        $(this).find("svg").append("<g id=\"appended\"></g>");
        $("#appended").load("test_inner.svg svg > *");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Already combined...</h3>
<div id="already-combined"><svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect x="1" y="1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" width="75" height="75"></rect>
  <g>
    <rect x="25" y="25" fill="none" stroke="#000000" width="25" height="25"></rect>
  </g>
</svg></div>
<h3>Combine in javascript...</h3>
<div id="combine"><svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect id="outer" x="1" y="1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" width="75" height="75"></rect>
<g id="appended"><rect id="inner" x="25" y="25" fill="none" stroke="#000000" width="25" height="25"></rect></g></svg></div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you show the DOM result (inspected)?

Comment: Just added it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut out the new code and then simply re-paste it back it in.

More specifically, change the following line...

`$("#appended").load("test_inner.svg svg > *");`

...to...

`$("#appended").load("test_inner.svg svg > *", function() {
    $("#combine").html($("#combine").html());
});`

It's almost like you have to force a manual screen or div refresh. That seems very bizarre, and rather annoying.

Some thoughts: It could be a bug in the browsers' implementation of SVG (but see my comments below about browsers). It could have something to do with dynamically inter-meshing two different DOM's, HTML and SVG. It could have something to do with relying on jQuery which, by its silence on the subject of SVG, seems like it has never guaranteed that it should work with SVG (and why some others have written plugins/libraries to get it to do that). Hmm.

*(By the way, this solution works in Firefox (v44.0.2) and Safari (v9.0.3), but even your original code shows no SVG at all in Chrome (v48.0.2564.103) or Opera (v35.0.2066.37). I didn't check Internet Explorer.)*

Answer (score 0):

This is something jQuery related. Using vanilla JS works for me:

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
svg.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<g>...</g>');
```